# How to handle the errors message RMG007 and CS8795 in Mapperly. And reduce to code

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, mapper, mapperly

In my project I am trying to implement Mapperly so I do that

```
using Riok.Mapperly.Abstractions;
namespace Application.Profiles;
[Mapper]
public partial class MapperlyMapper
{
    public partial UsersToRoleDto Map(UsersToRole usersToRole);
    public partial UsersToRoleDto Map(UsersToRole usersToRole)
    {
        return new UsersToRoleDto
        {
            User = usersToRole.User.FullName,
            Role = usersToRole.Role.Name
        };
    }
    public partial UsersToRole Map(UsersToRoleDto usersToRoleDto);
    public partial UsersToRole Map(UsersToRoleDto usersToRoleDto)
    {
        return new UsersToRole
        {
            User = new User { FullName = usersToRoleDto.User },
            Role = new Role { Name = usersToRoleDto.Role }
        };
    }
    public partial UserDto Map(User user);
    public partial User Map(UserDto userDto);
}
```

Now to the error messages if I remove the [Mapper] attribute then I get these error messages:

> 01-Error CS8795   Partial method 'MapperlyMapper.Map(User)' must have an
> implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.
> 02-Error CS8795    Partial method 'MapperlyMapper.Map(UserDto)' must have an
> implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.

on this line of code

```
public partial UserDto Map(User user);
public partial User Map(UserDto userDto);
```

But if I added the [Mapper] attribute I get these error messages:

> 01-Error RMG007   Could not map member
> Domain.Entities.UsersToRoleDto.Role of type string to
> Domain.Entities.UsersToRole.Role of type Domain.Entities.Role
>
> 02-Error RMG007   Could not map member
> Domain.Entities.UsersToRoleDto.User of type string to
> Domain.Entities.UsersToRole.User of type Domain.Entities.User
> on this line of code

```
public partial UsersToRole Map(UsersToRoleDto usersToRoleDto);
```

Would it be possible to solve both errors CS8795 and RMG007 at the same time?
Is there a way to reduce to code, such as using ReverseMap() in AutoMapper?

Comment: Read following : https://www.innovensa.co.uk/blog/comparison-of-object-mapper-libraries

Comment: thanks,I see this youtube video [The Best .NET Mapper to Use in 2023 By Nick Chapsas][https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8gSdQN2jWI&t=545s] that why I choose Mapperly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Timothy Makkison](https://github.com/TimothyMakkison)
I get the [answer](https://github.com/riok/mapperly/discussions/581#discussioncomment-6488628)
Hey, thanks for using Mapperly.
It would help if you shared User, UsersToRoleDto and Role etc but I came up with the following.
Mapperly can't know that you want path User.FullName of type User to map to path User of type string. the paths dont match. Instead it tries to map both User members together. This fails because it doesn't know how to convert from User -> string. I suggest you use MapProperty [docs](https://mapperly.riok.app/docs/configuration/flattening) or define how to convert from string -> User and User -> string

```
[Mapper]
public partial class Mapper
{
    [MapProperty("User.FullName", "User")]
    [MapProperty("Role.Name", "Role")]
    public partial UsersToRoleDto Map(UsersToRole usersToRole);

    [MapProperty("User", "User.FullName")]
    [MapProperty("Role", "Role.Name")]
    public partial UsersToRole Map(UsersToRoleDto usersToRoleDto);
}
```